# How can i record sound and read the sound simultaneously in android

Tags: android, audio

I am new in android. I want to make an app in which i can record the sound as well as read the sound simultaneously, like viber, without saving in external storage. I had put record sound and read sound both in async task with the help of executer on execute thread pool. But still i did not get any result. By storing in external device i have completed and i got the result by creating different project for recording and reading the sound. Pleases help I am getting so confused. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use [AudioRecord](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioRecord.html) to access the raw audio signal as an array of shorts.